# parsing xmll file through java

Tags: java, xml

I am using SAXParse in java to parse an xml file. I was successfully able to do this with one of the files but I moved to second file and tried reading an attribute I kept getting null. I have thought of every possible cause I can but I am not able to figure it out.

Here's a sample of xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProcessorStatusCode/>
<StatusCode>E</StatusCode>
   <ErrorNo>1852</ErrorNo>...
```

And here's my java code:

```
public class ReadXML
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,SAXException,                      ParserConfigurationeException
    {
        String OrderNum;
        SAXParserFactory parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser Sparser = parser.newSAXParser();
        ReadXML handler = new ReadXML();
        Sparser.parse("ErrorDescription.xml",handler);
     }

    public void characters(char[] buffer,int start,int length)
    {
        temp = new String(buffer, start, length);
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {
        temp = " ";
        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ErrorNo"))
        {
            //transaction = new Transaction();
            OrderNum = attributes.getValue(ErrorNo);
        }        
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
    {
        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ErrorNo"))
        {
            System.out.println(OrderNum);
        }

    }
}//end of class
```

Comment: Please format your code and your XML data so that it is more easily readable. Your code indentation is somewhat random, making it difficult to follow the logic of the code and thus to spot errors. Similarly your XML has no whitespace whatsoever which is kind of crazy.

Comment: Still crazy. I fixed your XML, but I don't have the time to fix your Java code. It's your responsibility to post readable code anyway. It makes sense that you will get a lot more good answers if we can read and understand your code, right?

Comment: I just fixed my xml and java code. I don't see anything messy on java side anymore.

Comment: `I don't see anything messy on java side anymore.` -- then we're just wasting time here, aren't we. Please study the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) standards document.

Comment: There is no chance this code compiles..

Comment: Your XML document is invalid. A document can only have one root element, but yours have two (ProcessorStatusCode and StatusCode).

Comment: OK, I formatted your code for you leaving in your [Allman style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) braces and making sure that *all blocks on the same level are indented the **same amount***, but next time, please put the effort in yourself to do this. Again this is your responsibility. Also consider changing to [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) style braces which are pretty much Java standard now.

Answer (score 0):

`String OrderNum` is declared as a local variable in the `main()` method, it should be a class member variable instead to be accessible in `ReadXML.startElement()`.